# Zooming in UIScrollView is not smooth

Tags: iphone

I created a minesweeper clone game in iphone. My implementaion of the cells in the grid is this, I created a UIView and added buttons in the UIView and then I added the UIView in a UIScrollView, but every time I zoom out or zoom in using zoomToRect method of UIScrollView the zooming is not smooth and the zoom out was distorted. How can implement smooth zooming in UIScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

I would try rendering your content view into a bitmap image when scrolling or zooming begins, and replacing the large grid of buttons with the bitmap until the scrolling/zooming is completed. The UIScrollViewDelegate protocol should provide you with the necessary information to know when to swap the bitmap in or out. Part of the problem is that your content view is so computationally intensive to render (all those buttons).

A more sophisticated approach would be to re-implement your game grid at a lower level using coreanimation and more fundamental touch event handling, but that might be overkill if the bitmap hack works well enough.

Answer (score 0):

You know how in the maps app, while panning or zooming, there are grey tiles that show up? That means that the iPhone is currently downloading the tiles. In Safari, there is a similar effect where Safari lays down checkered grey instead of webpage, as it is currently rendering it and will be just a moment. Both of these mean that scrolling will not wait for content to load before displaying the area, it will let scrolling be smooth.

You could try looking here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098234/optimized-image-loading-in-a-uiscrollview] for some ideas, and a point in the right direction would be to use threading to load views in the background while displaying grey in its place.